# Share Login Session with Safari browser & App

Tags: ios, swift, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0

I logged into my website using mobile safari browser which used Azure B2C login.
I also logged in into mobile app via MSAL library B2C login.

Now, I am opening the webpage inside the app with wkWebview or SFSafariView,
but login session is not exists, it ask for login again.

Can we get current login session to be share with both sides?

Do I have to use OAuth or something else like passed already logged in user token?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the login session in Azure B2C is only valid within the respective domain, and the website and app are considered separate domains.

Therefore, to share the login session between both, you would need to use methods such as OAuth flow or passing the user's already logged-in token. This involves transferring the authentication token from the website to the app, enabling the app to maintain the login session.

**There are several approaches you can consider:**

1. Using OAuth: This is a standard authentication protocol that is compatible with many services. You can pass the authentication token from the website to the app, allowing the app to maintain the login session.
2. Utilizing the MSAL library for performing silent login within the app. Silent login is performed when the user is already logged in and allows the app to renew the authentication token without additional user interaction. This helps in maintaining the login session within the app.
3. When opening web pages within the app using wkWebview or SFSafariView, you can explore the option of sharing cookies. By sharing cookies between the webview and the app, you can maintain the login session within the app.

It's important to note that if the website and app use the same domain or subdomain, cookie sharing might be a simpler option. However, it's crucial to consider security aspects, and other methods like OAuth or passing tokens may be more secure.